# SOLVING SEARCH QUERY

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am making a search query to be used in a form called 'ClassProfile'. The form is a continuous form and therefore lists records in a datasheet format. I have two textboxes on the form:

1. clsBox - used to enter a class name e.g 1T
2. nameBox - used to enter a teacher's name e.g Joe

Both of these textboxes will be used by the user to perform various searches based on the values contained in them. Next to them is a command button labeled 'Search'. The onClick() event of the search button contains the following code to perform the search:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

Dim strsearching As String
Dim strm As String
Dim tname As String

strm = Me.clsBox.Value
tname = Me.NameBox.Value

If Not IsNull(strm) Then
   If IsNull(strsearching) Then
   strsearching = "(([ClassProfile].[Class]) LIKE ""*" & strm & "*"")"
   End If
Else: strsearching = ""
End If

If Not IsNull(tname) Then
   If Not IsNull(strsearching) Then
   strsearching = strsearching & " AND (([ClassProfile].[Class Teacher]) LIKE ""*" & tname & "*"")"
   Else: strsearching = "(([ClassProfile].[Class Teacher]) LIKE ""*" & tname & "*"")"
   End If
Else: strsearching = ""
End If

Dim sql As String

If Not IsNull(strsearching) Then
   sql = "SELECT * FROM [ClassProfile] WHERE " & strsearching
   Else: sql = "ClassProfile"
End If

Me.RecordSource = sql

End Sub
```

When performing a search nothing happens to the recordset of the form, a sign the code is not working. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the very first `If` statement and follow it, noting any errors, and let us know what you get? Also, put a debug.print sql just before `Me.RecordSource = sql`.. Something can easily be amiss there.

Comment: Debugging doesn't seem to work at all. F5 brings no results on my immediate window, so does stepping into using F8. I have even made a function of the same and created a querydefs pointing it to a temporary query to pinpoint the problem. So far IsNull is a function that doesn't work on string variables; am therefore referencing the textboxes directly instead of storing them in variables. If I find a solution I will post. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When you click the button, `If Not IsNull(strm) Then` isn't highlighted in Yellow?

Comment: I am finding a couple of issues. First, if you don't supply a value in clsBox, get Null error. Second, but more important, your line 'If IsNull(strsearching) Then' first time in it IS null. Still looking at the code.

Comment: Yes, I am editing the code as follows to check for empty string `trim(clsBox.Value & vbnullstring) = vbnullstring`. Unfortunatel it also checks for spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED: Changed ISNULL(strsearching) checks.  Here is something that works. I changed your Null checks to avoid dealing with sometimes null values.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdSearch_Click()

Dim strsearching As String
Dim strm        As String
Dim tname       As String
Dim sql         As String

    strm = Nz(Me.clsBox.Value)
    tname = Nz(Me.NameBox.Value)

    strsearching = ""
    If strm <> "" Then
        strsearching = "(([ClassProfile].[Class]) LIKE ""*" & strm & "*"")"
    End If

    If tname <> "" Then
        If strsearching <> "" Then
            strsearching = strsearching & " AND (([ClassProfile].[Class Teacher]) LIKE ""*" & tname & "*"")"
        Else
            strsearching = "(([ClassProfile].[Class Teacher]) LIKE ""*" & tname & "*"")"
        End If
    End If

    If strsearching <> "" Then
       sql = "SELECT * FROM [ClassProfile] WHERE " & strsearching
    Else
       sql = "ClassProfile"
    End If

    Debug.Print sql

    Me.RecordSource = sql

End Sub
```

Comment: I have tried this but it only allows me to search for the second scenario in the four possible scenarios as listed below: 1. clsBox is empty and NameBox is empty 2. clsBox has a value and NameBox is empty 3. clsBox is empty and NameBox has a value 4. clsBox has a value and NameBox has a value. The rest do not work. Please help

Comment: I corrected the code. The issue was with the 'ISNULL(strsearching)' tests.

Answer (score 0):

Works like a charm Wayne. All compliments to you. Modified it just a bit for accuracy, here is the final code:

```
strm = Me.clsBox.Value
tname = Me.NameBox.Value

strsearching = ""
If Len(Trim(Me.clsBox.Value)) <> 0 Then
    strsearching = "(([ClassProfile].[Class]) LIKE ""*" & strm & "*"")"
End If

If Len(Trim(Me.NameBox.Value)) <> 0 Then
   If strsearching <> "" Then
   strsearching = strsearching & " AND (([ClassProfile].[Class Teacher]) LIKE ""*" & tname & "*"")"
   Else: strsearching = "(([ClassProfile].[Class Teacher]) LIKE ""*" & tname & "*"")"
   End If
End If

Dim sql As String

If strsearching <> "" Then
   sql = "SELECT * FROM [ClassProfile] WHERE " & strsearching
   Else: sql = "ClassProfile"
End If

Me.RecordSource = sql
```

Comment: I am curious.. with your code 'strm = Me.clsBox.Value', what happens the FIRST time you open the form and click the SEARCH button without providing ANY values? Do you have code elsewhere that sets those textboxes to empty? If not, why are you not getting error 94 - Invalid use of Null?

Comment: Good thinking, the textboxes themselves are unbound so I doubt any 'leaking' of data is possible; every time the form is closed their values are destroyed. Alternatively on the closeEvent() of the form I might reset their values to empty to prevent such an occurrence. Otherwise I get no error at all :)

Comment: This is weird then! It will not do any good to set values on close since they are not retained. If I open this form with your code and only click the 'Search' box, I get the Null error. Do you have other code that may set the boxes to empty? I'm running 2010.

Comment: I am running 2013, initially my `form.RecordSource = classprofile`. I set it as that from the design view and saved it as so. So each time it opens it automatically opens with all the records shown and no error appears.